# CSS :focus will not work with Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The issue is that :focus will not work in CSS. I am assuming that this might be because I am using Bootstrap, but I have tried everything that I was able to find about Bootstrap focus. Notice that from my snippet below, :focus works for the anchors that do not have any html attached to them.
Please help if you are able. Thanks!

```css
/* NAVIGATION */

.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}

#navbar .nav-link:focus {
  color: #8e0000;
  text-size-adjust: 1.4em;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 2px 1px black;
}

.logo-spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s;
  animation: spin 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 65px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #212529;
  border-top: 6px solid #212529;
}

#navbar {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .navbar-text {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Information meta tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="A portfolio page for Bernard Major">
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="King Major">
  <!--LOCAL-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS HOSTED-->
  <link rel="stylesheet"                  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"  crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--LOCAL-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <!-- FAVICON -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <title>King Major</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-wrapper nav-item">
          <div class="logo" id="logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="favicon.ico" alt="King's Brand                 Logo"></a>
          </div>
          <span class="brand" id="brand" style="animation-delay: 0s; animation-duration:                  3s">KING MAJOR</span>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-                      target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item focus">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor">ABOUT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor2">SKILLS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor3">PROJECTS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <!-- ABOUT -->
  <div class="blank" style="position: absolute">
    <a id="myanchor"></a>
  </div>
  <section id="about" class="section2">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h1>Welcome, <a href="#">let's talk!</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
              <p> I started independent web development two years ago, and haven't looked back. A couple of things I loveabout coding are those moments when tough projects are complete, or discovering a solution to a difficult problem. Take a look at my
                <a
                  href="#skills">skills</a>, and some of my recent
                  <a href="#projects">projects</a>. THANKS!
              </p>
              <a href="General_Resume.pdf" class="btn btn-outline-primary" target="__blank">Print My Resume</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- SKILLS -->
  <div class="blank" style="margin: -65px 0px 250px 0px; position: absolute;">
    <a id="myanchor2"></a>
  </div>

  <section id="skills" class="section3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h2>Tech I've learned:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col"><img class="code-icon" src="/portfolio2/static/media/code-                    icon.356b6fb2.svg">
              <p>JavaScript, HTML, CSS, MongoDB, Express, Node.js, Bootstrap, mySQL, AWS Cloud Storage, and more...</p>
              <h2>Tools I use:</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>Visual Studio Code</li>
                <li>Github</li>
                <li>Express</li>
                <li>Linux</li>
                <li>Axios</li>
                <li>npm</li>
                <li>Bash</li>
                <li>Chrome Developer Tools</li>
                <li>And more...</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your question here, what do you want the `link` to do? I see if you click on the links it shows `brown` color, what else you need? an `hover`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly you want the color to be highlighted.

There are 2 things you can do for the button.

1. [:active](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)
2. [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

you can choose which one you need, for you example I have used `:hover` which can serve your purpose.

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8));
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}

#navbar .nav-link:focus {
  color: #8e0000;
  text-size-adjust: 1.4em;
}

#navbar .nav-link:hover {
  color: yellow;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  text-size-adjust: 1.4em;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 2px 1px black;
}

.logo-spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s;
  animation: spin 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 65px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #212529;
  border-top: 6px solid #212529;
}

#navbar {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 200px;
  height: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .navbar-text {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: .1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Information meta tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="A portfolio page for Bernard Major">
  <meta http-equiv="author" content="King Major">
  <!--LOCAL-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css"> -->
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS HOSTED-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--LOCAL-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <!-- FAVICON -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <title>King Major</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-wrapper nav-item">
          <div class="logo" id="logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="favicon.ico" alt="King's Brand                 Logo"></a>
          </div>
          <span class="brand" id="brand" style="animation-delay: 0s; animation-duration:                  3s">KING MAJOR</span>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item focus">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor">ABOUT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor2">SKILLS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#myanchor3">PROJECTS
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>

  <!-- ABOUT -->
  <div class="blank" style="position: absolute">
    <a id="myanchor"></a>
  </div>
  <section id="about" class="section2">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card ">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h1>Welcome, <a href="#">let's talk!</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
              <p> I started independent web development two years ago, and haven't looked back. A couple of things I loveabout coding are those moments when tough projects are complete, or discovering a solution to a difficult problem. Take a look at my
                <a href="#skills">skills</a>, and some of my recent
                <a href="#projects">projects</a>. THANKS!
              </p>
              <a href="General_Resume.pdf" class="btn btn-outline-primary" target="__blank">Print My Resume</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- SKILLS -->
  <div class="blank" style="margin: -65px 0px 250px 0px; position: absolute;">
    <a id="myanchor2"></a>
  </div>

  <section id="skills" class="section3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h2>Tech I've learned:</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col"><img class="code-icon" src="/portfolio2/static/media/code-                    icon.356b6fb2.svg">
              <p>JavaScript, HTML, CSS, MongoDB, Express, Node.js, Bootstrap, mySQL, AWS Cloud Storage, and more...</p>
              <h2>Tools I use:</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>Visual Studio Code</li>
                <li>Github</li>
                <li>Express</li>
                <li>Linux</li>
                <li>Axios</li>
                <li>npm</li>
                <li>Bash</li>
                <li>Chrome Developer Tools</li>
                <li>And more...</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I said :focus. Not :active or :hover. 
When I click the link it should remain active(red) until a different link is clicked. Right now only the last two links actually have that type of functionality.

Comment: It is not an issue with the `:focus` it is with that `#myanchor` and `#myanchor2`, if you replace those 2 `href` with `#myanchor3` all 4 buttons work as expected. I assume it is not showing the desired output because when the `li` is clicked it moves from it's position it considers and event happened and it `unfocus` the object.

Comment: yes I kinda get that. That is sort of why I mentioned that there isn't any html on the two link that do actually work with :focus. But what I need is to understand why they don't work because I actually need those links to work with the #myanchor which is a component that solves another issue with a fixed nav.